# Latex Special Character/Font problem

Tags: latex

I am new to LaTeX, which I am trying to write my thesis with.
Can anybody guide me how to write [image]? or maybe it is a special font?
Thank you.

Comment: For future reference "I don't know the command" type LaTeX questions are probably better on [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) as the programingness coefficient is pretty low.

Comment: @dmckee: i tried there before posting this question, but i needed a minimum 10 reputation before i can upload an image (i currently have 0). that is why i posted it here.

Comment: Ah. If you have left the URL in the body of the post someone with more rep could have edited it into an image for you. In any case, it is not a huge deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the calligraphic form of `L`. You call it as `\mathcal{L}` inside a math environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: @ihf: PS: i do not recommend to anyone to use detextify, very dangerous app. i left the tab open accidentally and left for half an hour. when i came back my notebook was screaming and extremely hot (could have burned my legs) and had a constant 50% cpu usage. very very very bad programming!!!!

Comment: @Nagi, first time I hear about this. But detextify is still a useful application.

Comment: you just need to check it yourself. not that useful if you will end up with a melt laptop. anyway thank you.

Comment: @Nagi, I've just tested it and leaving the page open does bring the CPU to 100%, even when idle. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: tried it on both Opera and firefox, with the same result. the 50% cpu usage is when your tab is idle. try to draw and watch your cpu(s) getting numb! :D;D

Comment: I don't know the current state, but they have been mining bitcoins using a [Javascript implemented](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9042.0) bitcoin miner.